# Getting 204 Response while using Alexa Location API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My Code is:

```
URL =  "https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{}/settings" \
       "/address".format(context['System']['device']['deviceId'])
TOKEN =  context['System']['apiAccessToken']
#TOKEN =  session['user']['permissions']['consentToken']
HEADER = {'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(TOKEN)}


r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADER)

print('Status Code: '+str(r.status_code)+ "     " +str(r.reason))
```

I am have given permission to access my address. Earlier, i was getting 403 Forbidden response. Now after granting permission in skills setting i am getting 204 No content response. Please help me to resolve it!!

Comment: Please do  reply!

Comment: Are you using the correct apiEndpoint? Api endpoint  changes based on geographical location. Are you using the one in Sytem.apiEndpoint?

Comment: I still don't get it. I am not using my apiEndpoint while making the GET request right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try these things:

1. Make sure that you have an address saved for the associated device from which you are testing.  There is a chance that you will get this issue from test simulator. So add a real device, save address and test it.
2. Always use `apiEndpoint` from `context.System.apiEndpoint`. Depending upon the geographical location this will change.
3. Check whether you have granted permissions to access address. If not you will get `FORBIDDEN` error.